# Why does binding work in code behind but not declaratively?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm using an ASP.NET GridView. First, I tried to use declarative fields as below, but not to avail. I had an error stating that the binding object had no property Id or Name (but it actually did have them...)

```
 <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GlobalAnalyticsGridView" OnRowDataBound="GlobalAnalyticsGridView_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="false">                        
       <Columns>
             <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" Visible="false" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="WebAppName" HeaderText="Web Application" />                       
       </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

Then I tried by code, on the RowDataBound event. And it works just fine...

```
 protected void GlobalAnalyticsGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
             AnalyticsSettings settings = e.Row.DataItem as AnalyticsSettings;
             (e.Row.Cells[0]).Text = settings.Id;
             (e.Row.Cells[1]).Text = settings.WebAppName;
        }
    }
```

Any idea why is that?
Thanks for your lighting on this :)

Comment: Seems it should be "WebAppName" and not "Name"

Comment: When you use `GridVIew.DataBind()` method, actually it calls the `RowDataBound` event of GridView, if implemented.

Comment: @Magnus: My mistake. I tried different things and I ended up posting inconsitent example :/. I've corrected my initial post. So the bottom line is even with WebAppName, it says "object had no property WebAppName". While it works fine in code behind.

Comment: Im not sure what the issue is - this works for me but I use template fields rather than bound fields.  They are much more flexible btw.

Comment: @Asif.Ali: yes, I know. My question is why do I have to use this method instead of the DataField attribute directly?

Comment: @Julien - Don't use BoundFields - they provide no flexibility, use template fields like so: `<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="WP/CP Date" SortExpression="MsDate"><ItemTemplate><asp:Label ID="lblMSDate" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.MilestoneDate","{0:d}" )%>' ToolTip="Checklist WP/CP Date"> </asp:Label></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>`

Comment: I've followed your advices and use TemplateField instead but still the same error : DataBinding: 'se.sp.Settings.AnalyticsSettings' does not contain a property with the name 'WebAppName'. It does have this property since I can bind in the RowDataBound event... this is so weird!

`<asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="testLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.WebAppName") %>' />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>`